Why does Latex produce this error and how to fix it?
When I use \dot on the first line with an operator $\hat{a}$ and then go to a new line where there are two operators that are both dotted on top, there is an error where the letter from the first line is overlaid on the second operator on the next line. I can't figure out why this happens. Please help.
You can see the letter "a" is overlapped with the b that is on the second line. In fact, if you put any other letter under the dot, it will appear in the next line overlapping the second letter.
Here is the code
\begin{align}
    \dot{\hat{a}}&=...\\
    \dot{\hat{a}\hat{b}}&=
\end{align}

Here is the output


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.


It's a  hmm feature of the amsmath nested accent handling.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \dot{\hat{a}}&=...\\
    \dot{\hat{a}\ExpandArgs{c}\def{macc@tmp}{}\hat{b}}&=
\end{align}
\end{document}

